# Update/Insert Multi Hierarchical calculation from 2 tables with single level hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Create Table #BOM -- Table for Parent
(
Id Int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
ProductName Varchar(500),
Revision  Varchar(500),
Factory  Varchar(500)
)

Create Table #BOMDetails -- Table for Child
(
Id Int Primary Key Identity(1,1),
BomId Int Foreign Key references #BOM(Id),
ComponentName Varchar(500),
Revision  Varchar(500),
BomQty  Decimal(10,2),
ActualQty Decimal(10,2)
)

Insert Into #BOM(ProductName , Revision , Factory) Values('AA','A','JPD')
Insert Into #BOM(ProductName , Revision , Factory) Values('BA','A','JPD')
Insert Into #BOM(ProductName , Revision , Factory) Values('AB','A','JPD')
Insert Into #BOM(ProductName , Revision , Factory) Values('ABC','E','JPD')


Insert Into #BOMDetails(BomId ,ComponentName , Revision , BomQty) Values(1,'AB','A',1.20)
Insert Into #BOMDetails(BomId ,ComponentName , Revision , BomQty) Values(3,'ABC','E',1.50)
Insert Into #BOMDetails(BomId ,ComponentName , Revision , BomQty) Values(2,'BB','C',2)
Insert Into #BOMDetails(BomId ,ComponentName , Revision , BomQty) Values(4,'ABCD','C',2)

Select * from #BOM
Select * from #BOMDetails
```

[image]

I want to `Update` the Actual `Qty` As Multiplication of its All Parents `BomQty`.
Example in case of `ProductName` AB And ABC , Its child as well as `Parent`.
Actual `Quantity` of Component ABCD will be  => `(AA)1*(AB)1.2*(ABC)1.5*(ABCD)2 i.e (1 * 1.2 * 1.5 * 2) = 3.60`

Can anyone help to me to write `update` or `insert` `query` for the above calculation?

I have tried traversing the `table`, but it is not a good way as the data will be huge in lacs combinedly.

Comment: Why are you using floats for quantities? You do know that floats are only for scientific data right? Use int or decimal.

Comment: I don't get how the products are related to each other. Can you explain it a bit.

Comment: @siggemannen , they are not. but if you are talking about product 'AB' And 'ABC' as they exist in both the tables then these two element are both Parent(Product) and child(Component). They are derived from some product and they are deriving some component as well.

Comment: So the only link between them is that they both start `ABC`?? Do you not have a proper linking table between different `BOMDetails` rows?

Comment: #BOMDetails has BomId which is ID in #BOM Table which represent the Parent ID. eg. AA is Parent of AB